# Why won't my footer readjust to smaller screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

I have the webpage that I am working on. Everything about it works out properly in terms of responsiveness, however, only the footer doesn't work properly. I would like for the 3 sections of the footer to be displayed underneath each other when the screen is made smaller. Any help here is greatly appreciated. Check out my code below:

CSS:

```
    #left{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20px;
    color: white;
}
#centre{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40%;
    bottom: 10px;
    clear: inherit;
    min-width: 300px;
}
#right{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 78%;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
  div{display: block}
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
  html { background: url(assets/backupimage.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed; }
  #bgvid { display: none; }
  div{display: block}
}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is not the best way to layout a webpage, especially a responsive one. It removes elements out of the normal document flow which makes it hard for those elements to respond to viewport changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with hungerstar's comment - absolute positioning will make it needlessly difficult to make your webpage responsive.  That being said, it can be done.  You're already using @media screen and (max-width: 500px) syntax in your CSS but not using it to the full extent of its capabilities.  Inside of the section marked for the max-width: 500px section, you have the opportunity to totally redefine your css for a browser window smaller than 500px.  Inside those brackets, you can just redefine the CSS for your 3 divs.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
 #left{
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  bottom: 200px;
  left: 20px;
  color: white;
}
#centre{
  position: absolute;
   left: 20px;
  float: left;
  bottom: 100px;
  clear: inherit;
  min-width: 300px;
 }
#right{
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
}
}
```

So this will check the width of your screen, and when it becomes smaller than 500px, this CSS will be applied and your 3 divs will be repositioned all the way to the left, stacked on top of each other (i made up positions for them arbitrarily (100 and 200 px from the bottom).  You will need to redefine all this for the 800px-sized screen as well

Comment: All though noted by @borbesaur, I want to reiterate that this is less than ideal.

Comment: I understand that, but this did the trick well enough for this project. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning is a bad choice for page layout. Use floats or flexbox.

#### Float

```css
main,
footer > div {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}
main {
  min-height: 300px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
main strong {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
footer > div:nth-child( 2 ) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
@media ( min-width: 450px ) {
  footer > div {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
    <strong>Floated</strong> footer sections.
</main>
<footer>
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</footer>
```

#### Flexbox

```css
main,
footer > div {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}
main {
  min-height: 300px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
main strong {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
footer > div {
  flex: 1;
}
footer > div:nth-child( 2 ) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
@media ( min-width: 450px ) {
  footer {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
    <strong>Flex</strong> footer sections.
</main>
<footer>
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: you got a vote from me here.  This answer is super thorough.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely messing the layout with `position:absolute`

You need to do something like this:

```
  #left {
     float: left;
     color: white;
   }

   #centre {
     float: left;
     clear: inherit;
     min-width: 300px;
   }

   #right {
     float: left;
     color: white;
   }
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwfsppbc/)